# Can someone walk me through this stochastic differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a Brownian Motion and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Solve the following SDE:

$\text{d}X_t = -aX_t\text{dt} + b\text{d}W_t$.

I am familiar with the it$\hat{o}$ lemma, but I can never figure out how to choose a function for $f(t,x)$. Could someone walk me through the steps of this simple SDE, I would really appreciate it :)!

Update: I have solved it in the following way, although I am still a little unsure as to whether this solution is correct. Ok so this is my working:

$dXt+aXtdt=bdWt$

I then used the integrating factor with p(t)=at. Multiplying both sides by this I got:

$e^{at}dXt+aXte^{at}=be^{at}dWt$,

which I then noticed is equal to the product rule on the LHS:

$d(e^{at}Xt)=be^{at}dWt$

and then by integrating I obtained:

$e^{at}Xt=X0+\int^{t}_{0}be^{as}dWs$.

So my final solution is: $Xt=X_0e^{-at}+e^{-at}\int^{t}_{0}be^{as}dWS$. Is this correct?

Comment: Go read about integrating factors, try this problem again for while, then come back and show what you tried. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok so this is my working: 
$\text{d}X_t + aX_t\text{d}t = b\text{d}W_t$

I then used the integrating factor with $p(t) = at$. Multiplying both sides by this I got: $e^{at}dX_t + aX_te^{at} = be^{at}dW_t$. Which I notice to equal the product rule on the LHS: $d(e^{at}X_t) = be^{at}dW_t$ and then by integrating I obtained: $e^{at}X_t = X_0 + \int_{0}^{t}be^{as}dWs$. So my final solution is $X_t = X_0e^{-at} + e^{-at}\int_{0}^{t}be^{as}dW_S$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. You should also add additional insights directly to the question text, a new section perhaps to keep the chronology intact, and use the comments for notification of the addition.

Comment: Ok thank you. The only thing to notice is that I don't appear to have used the it$\hat{0}$ lemma in my working?

Comment: You used it without realizing, or rather it made no difference that you didn't formally apply it. Try to find the place in the above computation where you needed it.